# Issue : Empty <style amp-custom></style> tag coming in page source + AMP

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amp-html

Working on a next.js project, wanted to implement AMP pages for mobile view. I have added the following `<style>` tag in the `<head>` inside app.js:

`<style amp-custom="" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: MY_CSS_FILE}}>`

I am validating AMP via https://validator.ampproject.org/ and getting the following error -

`The tag "style amp-custom" appears more than once in the document.`

This is because of this  extra tag which is appearing in the page source and in turn failing the AMP validation.

According to AMP's official documentation, there should be only one mandatory  tag. Looking at the code, I am not sure where this extra tag is coming from and how to remove it.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: having the same issue, any luck?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this particular problem. I am getting the same issue.Please help if u know how to resolve this